# Magento 1.9.2 admin add street column in Customers by number of orders report

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a "street" column in admin → report → Customers by number of orders (Magento 1.9.2).

I have tried adding `join` query in 'app\code\core\Mage\Reports\Model\Resource\Customer\Orders\Collection.php':

```
protected function _joinFields($from = '', $to = '')
{
    $this->joinCustomerName()
        ->groupByCustomer()
        ->addOrdersCount()                 
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to, 'datetime' => true))
        ->join(array('p' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = p.parent_id', array(
                'street'
        ));
    return $this;
}
```

And in 'app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Customer\Orders\Grid.php':

```
$this->addColumn('street', array(
    'header'    => $this->__('street'),
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'street'
));
```

I am getting the main table data but not the fields I have joined.

[image]

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Are you looking for the data inside the street column ?

Comment: Yes, in this scenario i am joining sales_flat_order(main_table) and sales_flat_order_address. Getting data from sales_flat_order(main_table) but not getting the data from sales_flat_order_address

Answer (score 0):

In 'app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Customer\Orders\Grid.php'
You have to include renderer tag that will fetch the data from the respective module.

```
$this->addColumn('street', array(
    'header'    => $this->__('street'),
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'street',
    'renderer'  => 'namespace_module/adminhtml_module_renderer_streetname',

));
```

You have to include a method inside the renderer path that will return the street name. 
That's it